# Slider widget changing the position of the dot over a texfile

Tags: flutter

Is it possible, to modify the slider widget value through a input from outside? For example from a text field?
Writing 50 to the textfield for example, the dot of the slider would change to position 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have no idea why that would be necessary but here is the code

This is the **slider widget**

```
  double _value = 50;

  Slider SliderWidget() {
    return Slider(
      min: 0,
      max: 100, //set the maximum value because it will crash if the user enters a number greater than the value
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

and this is the column widget that contains the textformfield and the slider widget we created earlier.

```
Column(
      children: [
              TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  setState((){
                    _value = double.parse(val);
                  });
                },
              ),
              SliderWidget()
            ],
          )
```

1. Make sure the user only types numbers.
2. Make sure the user doesnt type a number greater than that of the maximum value of the slider.

Comment: Thanks @Danny. It is what i needed and wanted to know if it would be possible. The idea of this is to change the slider position in a IOT project. The flutter app is connected to a ESP32 and if i change some parameter on the ESP i would like also that the UI in flutter change accordantly.

Comment: You are welcome, Mark this as an answer if it worked for you please